# Adjust maximum download rate of rsync while running

Tags: linux, scripting

I need to download between two linux machines over a shaky connection. Rsync seems to be the best tool, but the thing is, I want do increase the bandwith rate limit on this process during the night.
How can I do that?

Any good suggestions on how to do this?
The best idea seems to me to be having a bash script that gets killed at specific times and then restarted with a script that checks the time and adjust the speed limit.

We can assume there are many rsyncs running all the time, so killall rsync will not work.

Comment: `rclone` allows for sophisticated bandwidth shaping based on the time of day. See its `--bwlimit` option.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of `rsync` have a `--time-limit=MINS` option. You say that the connection is shaky so you're going to need to loop around anyway. My suggestion would be to use `trickle` to manage the connection speed and force a restart of `rsync` every hour regardless of its state.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while :
do
    # Evening? Or day?
    time=$(date +%H%M)
    if [[ ${hour#0} -gt 2200 || ${hour#0} -lt 700 ]]
    then
        # After 10pm and before 7am
        up=100 down=10    # 100 KB/s up and 10 KB/s down
    else
        up=10 down=1      # 10 KB/s up and 1 KB/s down
    fi

    trickle -s -u $up -d $down -t 10 rsync -avzP --time-limit=60 /path/to/source/ remote:/path/to/destination/ && break

    # Take a breather
    sleep 60
done
```

Remember that in this example, if the time is rechecked at 06:59, the hour is still 6 so it will still restart `rsync` for an hour at full speed. Effectively this will letting it use your greater bandwidth until 8am, potentially an hour after you would expect.

Fix the up/down values to match your preferred bandwidth restrictions. They are in KB (kilobytes) per second, so you will need to adjust by the appropriate factor of 10 to convert from the more typical Internet connection speeds in Mb. Note that 1 Mb/s = 1000 Kb/s = 100 KB/s.

If you don't have the `--time-limit` option on your `rsync`, you can do much the same thing with the `timeout` utility.

```
timeout 60m trickle ... rsync ...
```